# Meteors "Template" is undefined in ie8, ie9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, meteor, internet-explorer-9

I'm debugging a problem with my Meteor application, when using IE8, IE9.
When using Chrome or Safari i haven't this problem:
In Ie errors:

### "Template" is undefined.

### "Meteor" is undefined.

If i wrap all templates from my files in 'if': 
    if (Meteor.isClient) {my Template code}; 
or if it is server code:
    if (Meteor.isServer) {my Template code}; 
It work in ie9, but not in ie8. 
I think Meteor create my templates in it's template, such as:

my code:
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.default.rendered = function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
               myFunction();
            });
        }
    }

Meteor wrap my template and in ie8 i can see my template and this:

```
(function () {
Template.__define__("default", (function () {
    var self = this;
    var template = this;
    return [ Spacebars.include(self.lookupTemplate("navbar")), "\n\n    ", HTML.DIV({
        "class": "content-wrapper"
    }, "\n        ", HTML.DIV({
        "class": "container"
    }, "\n\n            ", Spacebars.include(self.lookupTemplate("yield")), "\n\n         "), "\n    "), "\n\n    ", Spacebars.include(self.lookupTemplate("footer")) ];
    }));
})();
```

In application use libraries iron-router, nvd3js, bootstrap-3. may be it is their errors, but a think it is Meteors error. I'm use Meteor 0.8.0.
If my meteor application can work with ie8-9 - please, say me! And if you can - say how?  I'm will be very thankful!

Comment: You can prove that meteor itself is compatible with earlier versions of IE by testing with an empty project. It's likely that one of the packages you mentioned is broken or something else is going on with your code. I'd recommend starting with an empty project and adding one at a time until you see a failure.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when some other error causes the rest of the Meteor Javascript not to load properly. You should examine the first error that is printed out in the console, which is almost always the culprit.

If you can update your question with the whole error log, I can update my answer with the diagnosis.